Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@3d108ab9
ERROR: Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@3d108ab9.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@78bf145.

for fragment-1.5.4\res\values\values.xml:2:4:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="fragment_container_view_tag" type="id"/>
    <item name="special_effects_controller_view_tag" type="id"/>
    <item name="visible_removing_fragment_view_tag" type="id"/>
    <declare-styleable name="Fragment">
        <attr name="android:name"/>
        <attr name="android:id"/>
        <attr name="android:tag"/>
    </declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="FragmentContainerView">
        <attr name="android:name"/>
        <attr name="android:tag"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>

for core-1.15.0\res\values\values.xml:68:4:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr format="reference" name="nestedScrollViewStyle"/>
    <color name="androidx_core_ripple_material_light">#1f000000</color>
    <color name="androidx_core_secondary_text_default_material_light">#8a000000</color>
    <color name="call_notification_answer_color">#1d873b</color>
    <color name="call_notification_decline_color">#d93025</color>
    <color name="notification_action_color_filter">#ffffffff</color>
    <color name="notification_icon_bg_color">#ff9e9e9e</color>
    <dimen name="compat_button_inset_horizontal_material">4dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="compat_button_inset_vertical_material">6dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="compat_button_padding_horizontal_material">8dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="compat_button_padding_vertical_material">4dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="compat_control_corner_material">2dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="compat_notification_large_icon_max_height">320dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="compat_notification_large_icon_max_width">320dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="notification_action_icon_size">32dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="notification_action_text_size">13sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="notification_big_circle_margin">12dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="notification_content_margin_start">8dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="notification_large_icon_height">64dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="notification_large_icon_width">64dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="notification_main_column_padding_top">10dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="notification_media_narrow_margin">@dimen/notification_content_margin_start</dimen>
    <dimen name="notification_right_icon_size">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="notification_right_side_padding_top">4dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="notification_small_icon_background_padding">3dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="notification_small_icon_size_as_large">24dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="notification_subtext_size">13sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="notification_top_pad">10dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="notification_top_pad_large_text">5dp</dimen>
    <drawable name="notification_template_icon_bg">#3333B5E5</drawable>
    <drawable name="notification_template_icon_low_bg">#0cffffff</drawable>
    <item name="accessibility_action_clickable_span" type="id"/>
    <item name="accessibility_custom_action_0" type="id"/>
    <item name="accessibility_custom_action_1" type="id"/>
    <item name="accessibility_custom_action_10" type="id"/>
    <item name="accessibility_custom_action_11" type="id"/>
    <item name="accessibility_custom_action_12" type="id"/>
    <item name="accessibility_custom_action_13" type="id"/>
    <item name="accessibility_custom_action_14" type="id"/>
    <item name="accessibility_custom_action_15" type="id"/>
    <item name="accessibility_custom_action_16" type="id"/>
    <item name="accessibility_custom_action_17" type="id"/>
    <item name="accessibility_custom_action_18" type="id"/>
    <item name="accessibility_custom_action_19" type="id"/>
    <item name="accessibility_custom_action_2" type="id"/>
    <item name="accessibility_custom_action_20" type="id"/>
    <item name="accessibility_custom_action_21" type="id"/>
    <item name="accessibility_custom_action_22" type="id"/>
    <item name="accessibility_custom_action_23" type="id"/>
    <item name="accessibility_custom_action_24" type="id"/>
    <item name="accessibility_custom_action_25" type="id"/>
    <item name="accessibility_custom_action_26" type="id"/>
    <item name="accessibility_custom_action_27" type="id"/>
    <item name="accessibility_custom_action_28" type="id"/>
    <item name="accessibility_custom_action_29" type="id"/>
    <item name="accessibility_custom_action_3" type="id"/>
    <item name="accessibility_custom_action_30" type="id"/>
    <item name="accessibility_custom_action_31" type="id"/>
    <item name="accessibility_custom_action_4" type="id"/>
    <item name="accessibility_custom_action_5" type="id"/>
    <item name="accessibility_custom_action_6" type="id"/>
    <item name="accessibility_custom_action_7" type="id"/>
    <item name="accessibility_custom_action_8" type="id"/>
    <item name="accessibility_custom_action_9" type="id"/>
    <item name="line1" type="id"/>
    <item name="line3" type="id"/>
    <item name="tag_accessibility_actions" type="id"/>
    <item name="tag_accessibility_clickable_spans" type="id"/>
    <item name="tag_accessibility_heading" type="id"/>
    <item name="tag_accessibility_pane_title" type="id"/>
    <item name="tag_on_apply_window_listener" type="id"/>
    <item name="tag_on_receive_content_listener" type="id"/>
    <item name="tag_on_receive_content_mime_types" type="id"/>
    <item name="tag_screen_reader_focusable" type="id"/>
    <item name="tag_state_description" type="id"/>
    <item name="tag_transition_group" type="id"/>
    <item name="tag_unhandled_key_event_manager" type="id"/>
    <item name="tag_unhandled_key_listeners" type="id"/>
    <item name="tag_window_insets_animation_callback" type="id"/>
    <item name="text" type="id"/>
    <item name="text2" type="id"/>
    <item name="title" type="id"/>
    <integer name="status_bar_notification_info_maxnum">999</integer>
    <string name="call_notification_answer_action">Answer</string>
    <string name="call_notification_answer_video_action">Video</string>
    <string name="call_notification_decline_action">Decline</string>
    <string name="call_notification_hang_up_action">Hang Up</string>
    <string name="call_notification_incoming_text">Incoming call</string>
    <string name="call_notification_ongoing_text">Ongoing call</string>
    <string name="call_notification_screening_text">Screening an incoming call</string>
    <string name="status_bar_notification_info_overflow">999+</string>
    <style name="TextAppearance.Compat.Notification" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent"/>
    <style name="TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info">
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorSecondary</item>
    </style>
    <style name="TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Line2" parent="TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info"/>
    <style name="TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Time">
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorSecondary</item>
    </style>
    <style name="TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent.Title"/>
    <style name="Widget.Compat.NotificationActionContainer" parent=""/>
    <style name="Widget.Compat.NotificationActionText" parent=""/>
    <declare-styleable name="Capability">
        
        <attr format="reference" name="queryPatterns"/>
        
        <attr format="boolean" name="shortcutMatchRequired"/>
    </declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="ColorStateListItem">
        
        <attr name="android:color"/>
        
        <attr format="float" name="alpha"/>
        <attr name="android:alpha"/>
        
        <attr format="float" name="lStar"/>
        <attr name="android:lStar"/>
    </declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="FontFamily">
        
        <attr format="string" name="fontProviderAuthority"/>
        
        <attr format="string" name="fontProviderPackage"/>
        
        <attr format="string" name="fontProviderQuery"/>
        
        <attr format="string" name="fontProviderFallbackQuery"/>
        
        <attr format="reference" name="fontProviderCerts"/>
        
        <attr name="fontProviderFetchStrategy">
            <!-- The blocking font fetch works as follows.
              First, check the local cache, then if the requested font is not cached, request the
              font from the provider and wait until it is finished.  You can change the length of
              the timeout by modifying fontProviderFetchTimeout.  If the timeout happens, the
              default typeface will be used instead. -->
            <enum name="blocking" value="0"/>
            <!-- The async font fetch works as follows.
              First, check the local cache, then if the requested font is not cached, trigger a
              request the font and continue with layout inflation. Once the font fetch succeeds, the
              target text view will be refreshed with the downloaded font data. The
              fontProviderFetchTimeout will be ignored if async loading is specified. -->
            <enum name="async" value="1"/>
        </attr>
        
        <attr format="integer" name="fontProviderFetchTimeout">
            <!-- A special value for the timeout. In this case, the blocking font fetching will not
              timeout and wait until a reply is received from the font provider. -->
            <enum name="forever" value="-1"/>
        </attr>
        
        <attr format="string" name="fontProviderSystemFontFamily"/>
    </declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="FontFamilyFont">
        
        <attr name="fontStyle">
            <enum name="normal" value="0"/>
            <enum name="italic" value="1"/>
        </attr>
        
        <attr format="reference" name="font"/>
        
        <attr format="integer" name="fontWeight"/>
        
        <attr format="string" name="fontVariationSettings"/>
        
        <attr format="integer" name="ttcIndex"/>
        
        <attr name="android:fontStyle"/>
        <attr name="android:font"/>
        <attr name="android:fontWeight"/>
        <attr name="android:fontVariationSettings"/>
        <attr name="android:ttcIndex"/>
    </declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="GradientColor">
        
        <attr name="android:startColor"/>
        
        <attr name="android:centerColor"/>
        
        <attr name="android:endColor"/>
        
        <attr name="android:type"/>

        
        
        <attr name="android:gradientRadius"/>

        
        
        <attr name="android:centerX"/>
        
        <attr name="android:centerY"/>

        
        
        <attr name="android:startX"/>
        
        <attr name="android:startY"/>
        
        <attr name="android:endX"/>
        
        <attr name="android:endY"/>

        
        <attr name="android:tileMode"/>
    </declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="GradientColorItem">
        
        <attr name="android:offset"/>
        
        <attr name="android:color"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>

Task :app:mergeDebugResources
C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\MobileApplication.gradle\caches\8.9\transforms\8a31b71d04ce0df69968e6c9189f456f\transformed\fragment-1.5.4\res\values\values.xml:2:4: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\MobileApplication.gradle\caches\8.9\transforms\8de5f963b0d5ca17e8456c5ef3c506c1\transformed\core-1.15.0\res\values\values.xml:68:4: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.


Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile values resource file C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\MobileApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\debug\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml. Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@3d108ab9.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@78bf145.). Check logs for more details.

LINE 68:   <item name="line3" type="id"/>
Can someone help me to resolve this, Thankyou!
